# How can I convert this object into a list and display on HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I have a function that can take user input and count the occurrence of each letter of the word. And now I can get it return into an object but cannot append the list on html

```
const wordForm = document.querySelector("#word-form");
const letterList = document.querySelector("#letter-list");
const newWord = document.querySelector("#new-word")




wordForm.addEventListener("submit", function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    const wordlist = document.querySelector("#word-input").value
    var obj = {};
    wordlist.split('').forEach(function (e) {
        obj.hasOwnProperty(e) ? obj[e] = ++obj[e] : obj[e] = 1
    })
    console.log(Object.keys(obj));
    letterList.append +=(Object.keys(obj))
    letterList.append +=(Object.values(obj))



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="count.css">

  <title>Letter Counter</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="word-form">
    <input type="text" id="word-input" value="hello">
    <button id="new-word">Count</button>
  </form>

  <ul id="letter-list">
    <li class="list">h: 1</li>
    <li class="list">h: 1</li>
    <li class="list">h: 1</li>
    <li class="list">h: 1</li>
  </ul>

  <script src="count.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I need something like this to display on HTML:

```
hello
.h: 1
.e: 1
.l: 2
.o: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot append text directly to the list element. You should create `li` elements and use the `appendChild` method. Here is an example how you can achieve that:

```
wordForm.addEventListener("submit", function () {
    event.preventDefault();

    const wordlist = document.querySelector("#word-input").value;
    const obj = {};
    wordlist.split('').forEach(function (letter) {
       obj[letter] = obj[letter] ? ++obj[letter] : 1;
    });

    // first remove all old children
    while (letterList.hasChildNodes()) {
       letterList.removeChild(letterList.lastChild);
    }

    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
       const li = document.createElement("li");
       li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${key}: ${value}`));
       letterList.appendChild(li);
    }
});
```

You should also remove all old child nodes to achieve better results.

Answer (score 0):

Do you wanna something like this? I just use loop and innerHTML method.

```js
const wordForm = document.querySelector("#word-form");
const letterList = document.querySelector("#letter-list");
const newWord = document.querySelector("#new-word");

wordForm.addEventListener("submit", function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    const wordlist = document.querySelector("#word-input").value
    var obj = {};
    wordlist.split('').forEach(function (e) {
        obj.hasOwnProperty(e) ? obj[e] = ++obj[e] : obj[e] = 1
    })
  const objectvalues = Object.values(obj);
  const objectkeys = Object.keys(obj);
  for(i=0;i<objectvalues.length;i++){
  letterList.innerHTML += '.' + objectkeys[i] + ': ' + objectvalues[i] + '</br>';
  };
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>Letter Counter</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="word-form">
    <input type="text" id="word-input" value="hello">
    <button id="new-word">Count</button>
  </form>

  <ul id="letter-list"></ul>

</body>

</html>
```